# jquery - want to get value from a page that renders two ways (view & edit)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

(jquery newbie alert!)

I'm trying to use JQuery / javascript to get a value from a text field, then check if it's >14 days old.  My problem is that the page (and my field's HTML) is different depending on if the app/page is in 'edit' mode or in 'view' mode.

Is it possible to write a selector that gets the val wrapped inside a span, regardless of whether it's inside an input field or is just text inside the span?  Can one get the value via span().val(), for example?  I'm trying, but not succeeding so far.

Here's the HTML snippets:

Edit mode:

```
<td class="m1234Bottom" style="width:35%;">
    <span id="ABC123" class="Datetime">
    <div class="dateElement" id="ABC188c">
        <input name="ABC$123ccc"
           type="text">
        <a class="date"></a>
        <a style="display: none;" class="time"></a>
    </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

View mode:

```
<td class="m1234Bottom" style="width:35%;">
    <span id="ABC123">
        12/23/2012
    </span>
</td>
```

I can get the 'edit' value with:

```
$("input[name*='123ccc']".each(function() {
    var outv= $(this).val();
    alert(outv);
});
```

Is there a better JQuery that'll find that value in both edit or view code?

Sorry if that selection/each/this.val chaining makes you cringe.  I'm just hours into exploring jquery for the first time.  Feel free to mock or point out better ways; I don't even need an explanation -- I can RTFWebDoc.  But if someone doesn't intervene, I'm stuck doing this via javascript: next up will be a nasty if/then codeblock, then another few hours of trial-and-error and stackoverflow-reading to learn jquery error checking for null-values, then rediscovering javascript's string-to-date functions before I finally get to my goal: 'is this date >14 days old?'

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to either get a text value of span id #ABC123 or value of an input with name ABC$123ccc.

In that case, basing on the snippet you provided you can try the following way:

```
var span = $('#ABC123');

//check if span has input child
if (span.find('input').length > 0) {
    //get value from input field
    var date = span.find('input').val();
}
else {
    //get text date from the span
    var date = span.text();
}
```

Comment: data variable cannot be accessed outside of the if/else , declare it before that

Comment: Thanks, nice insights.  I pulled the 'var date' out to fix the scope problem (thanks sushanth!).  However, could that span.find be returning a null object that is still parsed as a 'true' for that if statement?  Cuz I get the first statement when in view or edit mode.

Comment: Actually that was an error. `.find()` returns an array of elements so you need to check if there is anything in that array. I've corrected the code

Comment: Testing it now.  Also, in my digging I've learned a simplification for your code: span.find().length >0 parses the same as span.find().length  without the >0 -- since javascript false == 0, true !=0.  Admittedly, yours is explicit which many would argue in favor of.... Let the 'short/implicit vs. explicit' debate begin!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('#ABC123').find('input').length > 0 ? value = $('#ABC123').find('input').val() : value = $('#ABC123').text();
    console.log(value);
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/63QF6/41/

In the fiddle, change one of the span's ID's to anything besides #ABC123 to mimic changing view.

Comment: Sorry, I can't change the code I'm reaching into.  All I've got is the ability to insert my own custom js/jquery snippet.

Comment: in that case we need even less code :). see updated - I copied the code in your question verbatim. note that in the fiddle it will not log both the values because the ID selector can only select 1 element even if multiple elements share ID's.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you!

Edit: and thanks for doing it via jsfiddle.  That was useful for me to tweak and edit to adapt for something I'd sanitized out that gave me trouble.

Specifically, the COTS application I'm using has big nasty UID strings whose prefix components change irrationally (but the end bit is fine).  Ended up with this JQuery snippet:

  $("span[id$='ABC123c']").find('input').length > 0 ? obj1 = $("span[id$='ABC123c']").find('input').val().trim() : obj1  = $("span[id$='ABC123c']").text().trim();

Comment: Nice... 4 mins in and the 5-minute counter for editing my comments failed.  Here's the clean version of that code:

Specifically, the COTS application I'm using has big nasty UID strings whose prefix components change irrationally (but the end bit is fine).  Ended up with this JQuery snippet:

  `$("span[id$='ABC123c']").find('input').length > 0 ? obj1 = $("span[id$='ABC123c']").find('input').val().trim() : obj1 = $("span[id$='ABC123c']").text().trim();`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not use the val() function for span. By definition on the JQuery website:

The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

If you want to retrieve the value of the span, you should use .text() or .html() because the content of the span is not a "value" but the content of the span (The span coulb contain other node, unlike the input).

But you can make a unique function like:

```
function retrieveValue()
{
    // Retrieve the element (not guess yet)
    var spanOrInput = $("#ABCD123");

    // Try to guess if its an input or a span
    var type = spanOrInput.attr('type');
    if (typeof type == "undefined" || !type)
        return spanOrInput.val();
    else
        return spanOrInput.html();
}
```

Comment: It won't work as in both cases `$('#ABC123')` will be a span element. Input elemnt in the second case do not have id, only name

Answer (score -1):

is there any reason why you can't do this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidtype" />
```

then based on weather it is view mode or edit mode store that in this hidden field then,

```
 $(function(){
     if ($('#hidtype').val() == '1') {   //or what ever you use to set state
     // code here for that mode
     }
     else{
    // code for other type of mode
     }     
 });
```

if you insist on doing it that way you can check if the input exists like this

```
if( $('#ABC123 input').length ) {
//this means the input exists - handle from here
}
```

Comment: Can't change the code I'm reaching into.  All I've got is the ability to hook in my own custom js/jquery snippet.